# Migrating files compressed with gzcompress() [PHP]

Tags: php

I have some files on `home/domain.com/path/to/file.txt` with data compressed using `gzcompress()`. I need to move those files to `home/otherdomain.com/newpath/to/file.txt`. I copied the files, but when I change the path on the file that read the compressed data I get this warning: `gzuncompress(): data error`.

I already tried to copy the files again in case of an error during the copy but i didn't solve it. If I try with the old URI it works well.

How do I solve it and what can I do to avoid the same issue in case I need to move the files again in the future (ie: a server migration)?

Comment: Did you try to manually download the files from the new location and compare them with the original files? You're reading the files using HTTP, not locally, did I understand it right?

Comment: Well, no, I am reading it with the `home/domain.com/path/file.txt`, I didn't expain it well, but I am not using HTTP. Both domain are in the same server.

Comment: So please change it in your question. You're writing about the URL there, it should be just a path. In that case, did you check that PHP has permissions to read the files from the new location?

Comment: Changed. Yes, it has permission, I receive the content of the file, I just can't uncompress it.

Comment: Ok, Dawid, I checked the MD5 of the files and are pretty differents... How can it be if I am copying the files?

Comment: Problem solved. I was downloading the files and uploading it again with Filezilla, But then I transfer the files internally and it worked fine. Looks like it may be a Filezilla's bug with this kind of compression.

Comment: I see. Why did you do that? It's pretty weird, if you just need to move files locally, to download and upload them. Wasn't your Filezilla configured to transfer them as text files (instead of binary)?

Comment: Yeah, is kind of weird... but it was only a folder, I alredy had Filezilla open... I was not logged on the server... you know, It seemed a good idea. And again, you was right about the transfer configuration.